# Differentiable at $x=a$ implies continuous at $x=a$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Consider the function $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} x^2-4 & \text{ if }x\leq 2\\4x+3&\text{ if } x\gt 2\end{array}\right.$$

This function is differentiable at $x=2$ since $\lim_{h\to 0^{\pm}}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}=4$ (EDIT: this actually isn't true but it is true that $\lim_{x\to 2^-}f^\prime (x)=4=\lim_{x\to 2^+}f^\prime(x)$); however, it's not continuous at $x=2$.

How is that possible, doesn't differentiability at $x=a$ imply continuity at $x=a$?

This question came up when I tried to answer the question of finding $a$ and $b$ such that the function $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} ax^2-b & \text{ if }x\leq 2\\bx+3&\text{ if } x\gt 2\end{array}\right.$$

The solution is achieved by finding conditions on $a$ and $b$ such that it's continuous, and also such that the left/right derivates exist. The left/right derivative question gives $4a=b$. With the condition of continuity you get the additional condition that $4a-b=2b+3$, giving a unique solution. But doesn't differentiability imply continuity? What's wrong with just solving $4a=b$ like in the first example above?

Comment: It is more so that differentiability requires continuity rather than implies it.

Comment: If I can't assume that $\lim_{x\to 2}f^\prime(x)=\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}$, then how do I solve my second question? The solution uses that $\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)$ and that $\lim_{x\to2^-}f^\prime(x)=\lim_{x\to2^+}f^\prime(x)$...how does that work? Why can we get away without using the difference quotient?

Comment: It is simply the premise of the problem.  Since you don't know whether or not the function is continuous at $x=2$, before you find differentiability at $x=2$, you must first account for its continuity.  Compare this to a problem that begins with something like _Let $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such that..._ (in which case you can assume $F$ to be continuous).

Comment: Your limit computation at $2^+$ is wrong. It is *not* $4$.

Comment: Perhaps my question is, when can we use that $\lim_{x\to2^+}f^\prime(x)=\lim_{x\to2^-}f^\prime(x)$ to check if a function is differentiable?  It seems that if the function is continuous, then we can use that to verify differentiability?

Comment: for my second question, i get that $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}=b$ and $\lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}=4a$....so for the function to be differentiable, don't I just need $b=4a$? Apologies to ask so many questions, thanks for all the help!

Comment: [A function might be differentiable without $f'(x)$ being continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220829/what-is-the-difference-between-continuous-derivative-and-derivative)

Comment: Yes, for differentiability you need $4a=b$. Since differentiability implies continuity, you also have $f(2^-)=f(2^+)=f(2)$. Consider $f(2^+)=f(2)$ giving $4a-b=2b+3$.

Comment: Thank you, it just seems that the condition $4a=b$ should be enough, since differentiability implies continuity. If $b=4a$ the function should already be continuous, since it's differentiable...the equation $4a-b=2b+3$ should hold if $4a=b$...it throws me off there is still one more condition to check.

Comment: @user162520 I am editing my answer. But I would like you to calculate the RHD. You will see that the RHD exists iff $4a=3b+3$.

Answer (score 3):

The function is not differentiable at $2$ because $RHD$ is $$\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{[4(2+h)+3]-0}h\to\infty$$Note that it is only the LHD which is $4$.

---

It is given that the function is differentiable at $2$. $$\begin{align*}LHD&=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(2)-f(2-h)}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{4a-b-[a(2-h)^2-b]}h=4a\\RHD&=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}h=\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{2b+hb+3-[4a-b]}h\end{align*}$$

Note that for the $RHD$ to exist, the limit must have the $0/0$ form since the denominator tends to $0$. The numerator will tend to $0$ iff $2b+3-[4a-b]=3b+3-4a=0$, giving you the $RHD=b$.

Equating the $RHD$ and $LHD$ gives $4a=b$ and existence of $RHD$ requires $4a=3b+3$ which is also the condition which we obtained from analyzing the continuity of $f$. Thus there is no need to consider continuity separately.

Comment: Why can't I just say that $\lim_{x\to 2^-}f^\prime(x)=4$ and also $\lim_{x\to 2^+}f^\prime(x)=4$

Comment: That is true, but note that $RHD=\lim_{x\to2^+}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}\ne\lim_{x\to2^+}f'(x)$ in general. In fact $f'(x)$ does not exist at $x=2$ even though the limits as you observed exist.

Comment: that blows my mind! Why doesn't $\lim_{x\to2^+}f^\prime(x)=\lim_{x\to2^+}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}$

Comment: The LHS in your expression gives the limit of the derivative from the right of $2$ and assuming differentiability, the RHS gives the value of the derivative **at** $2$. For discontinuous $f'$, they may not agree. The same happens with $y=|x|$. The function is not differentiable at $0$ but the RHL of $f'(x)$ is $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems miraculous that just by solving the continuity condition, and the 'continuity of $f^\prime(x)$' equation, we arrive at the same answer. If in question 2 above I had some non-polynomial function, it would very hard to solve with limits of difference quotients. But for some reason, checking both continuity and 'continuity of the derivative' will give 2 equations on a and b...I still don't really see why this works, because I agree the derivative might not be continuous.

Comment: Where have we analyzed the continuity of the derivative? We are checking for the **existence** of the derivative at $2$ i.e. can we even write $f'(2)$ i.e. differentiability of $f$ at $2$.The RHD, LHD if they exist and are equal, give the value of $f'(2)$, not the value RHL/LHL of $f'(x)$ at $2$.

Comment: I'm saying that if you take the condition that RHL=LHL of $f^\prime(x)$ and RHL=LHL of $f(x)$, then you get the unique answer $b=-3/2$ and $a=-3/8$. I'm trying to understand why that works, when really the more accurate way to do is how you've done above...checking that RHD=LHD

Comment: The LHL of $f^\prime(x)$ is $4a$ because $b$ is a constant.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(2)=0$ and that therefore$$\lim_{x\to2^+}\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to2^+}\frac{4x+3}{x-2}=\infty.$$So, $f$ is *not* differentiable at $2$.